# Get All URL Parameters EXCEPT One

Tags: php, mysql

I have a pagination script linked to a MySQL query that I can filter. When the results are not filtered and all rows are being shown I have a next link that says "?pg=2" and so on(depending on how many results and such). Once I filter what I want shown my URL contains other parameters like ?certifications=VALUE&state=VALUE.

These lines handle my pagination links.

```
echo "<a href='?pg=".($pg-1)."' class='paginationButton'>PREVIOUS</a> \n";

echo "<a href='?pg=".($pg+1)."' class='paginationButton'>NEXT</a> \n";
```

I added $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] to each to try to add the url parameters to the links. It works BUT it also adds the ?pg parameter each time it is clicked(basically if next is clicked twice it does this ?certifications=VALUE&state=VALUE&pg=3&pg=2.

How can I make it to where if &pg is already set it does not duplicate it in the URL?

==============================================================================

## FULL CODE HERE

```
$start=0;
$limit=3;

if(isset($_GET['pg']))
{
$pg=$_GET['pg'];
$start=($pg-1)*$limit;
}
else { 
$pg = 1;
}
$sql = mysql_query($query);

$conditions = "SELECT * FROM pilotOperators WHERE 1=1";
# append condition for signage (if required)
if(isset($_GET['signage'])) {
 $conditions .= " AND signage='1'";
}
 # append condition for certifications (if required)
  if(isset($_GET['certifications'])) {
   $certifications = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['certifications']);
   $conditions .= " AND certifications='$certifications'";
}
# append condition for state (if required)
if(isset($_GET['state'])) {
 if($_GET['state'] != "Select State") {
   $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['state']);
   $conditions .= " AND state='$state'";
}
}
$conditions .= " Limit $start, $limit";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $conditions);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "\n <table border='0' class='resultTable' width='75%'> \n";
echo "<tr> \n";
echo "<td width='120px'>ID: </td> \n";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
echo "<tr> \n";
echo "<td>Name: </td> \n";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
echo "<tr> \n";
echo "<td>Phone: </td> \n";
echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
echo "<tr> \n";
echo "<td>Alt. Phone: </td> \n";
echo "<td>" . $row['alt_phone'] . "</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
echo "<tr> \n";
echo "<td>Fax: </td> \n";
echo "<td>" . $row['fax'] . "</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
echo "<tr> \n";
echo "<td>Email: </td> \n";
echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
echo "<tr> \n";
echo "<td>Website: </td> \n";
echo "<td><a href='" . $row['website'] . "' target='_blank'>" . $row['website'] . "</a></td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
echo "<tr> \n";
echo "<td>City: </td> \n";
echo "<td>" . $row['city'] . "</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
echo "<tr> \n";
echo "<td>State: </td> \n";
echo "<td>" . $row['state'] . "</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
echo "<tr> \n";
echo "<td>Certifications: </td> \n";
echo "<td>" . $row['certifications'] . "</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
echo "<tr> \n";
echo "<td>Top Sign: </td> \n";
echo "<td>";
if($row['signage'] = 1) {
 echo "Has Top Sign";
}
else {
 echo "Top Sign Not Listed";
}
echo "</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
echo "</table> \n\n";
}

$countconditions = "SELECT * FROM pilotOperators WHERE 1=1";
# append condition for signage (if required)
if(isset($_GET['signage'])) {
   $countconditions .= " AND signage='1'";
}
# append condition for certifications (if required)
if(isset($_GET['certifications'])) {
   $certifications = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['certifications']);
   $countconditions .= " AND certifications='$certifications'";
 }
# append condition for state (if required)
if(isset($_GET['state'])) {
 if($_GET['state'] != "Select State") {
   $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['state']);
   $countconditions .= " AND state='$state'";
}
}
$rows = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, $countconditions));

$total=ceil($rows/$limit);
echo "<div id='paginationLinks'> \n";
if($pg>1)
{
echo "<a href='?pg=".($pg-1)."&".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']."' class='paginationButton'>PREVIOUS</a> \n";
}
if($pg!=$total)
{
echo "<a href='?pg=".($pg+1)."&".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']."' class='paginationButton'>NEXT</a> \n";
}

echo "<ul class='page'> \n";
for($i=1;$i<=$total;$i++)
{
if($i==$pg) { echo "<li class='current'>".$i."</li> \n"; }

else { echo "<li><a href='?id=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li> \n"; }
}
echo "</ul> \n";
echo "</div> \n";
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Take a look at `parse_str` it is a PHP function for parsing querystrings into an associative array. When you have that you can simply replace the pg entry in the array and then stringify it back to a query string with `http_build_query`. Take a look at: 
https://php.net/parse_str

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$q = http_build_query(array_merge($_GET, ["pg" => $pg+1]));

<a href="?$q">..</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try replace your:

```
href='?pg=".($pg+1)."&".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']."'
```

with something like:

```
$allParams = $_GET;
$allParams['pg'] = $pg+1;
$queryString = '?';
foreach ($allParams as $param=>$param_val) {
    if ($queryString != '?') $queryString .= '&';
    $queryString .= $param.'='.urlencode($param_val);
}
...
echo "<a href='$queryString' class=...
```

Comment: Just tried it. When I clicked the link the URL parameters became this: ?pg=?pg=1

Comment: hold on my mistake let me try something else. I left something in the url that shouldnt have been :)

Answer (score 0):

You can erase pg from your query string and then replace it again. If it isn't there, you don't remove it, but still replace it.

```
preg_replace('/(^|&)pg=[0-9]+&/','\1',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].'&').'pg='.($pg+1)
```

What this does is:

1. Stick a & at the end of the end of the query string - we'll need that.
2. Look for pg=### following beginning of the string or &
3. Erase the pg=###
4. Tack on the pg=$pg+1 a the end of the query string.

Why check for & before and after? I don't want to accidentally replace a variable like 'apg=54'